# Does System.get_property('phone_id') always return a value?

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

The [documentation](http://rhodesapi.rhomobile.com/system-api#getproperty) says nothing about possible return values. I have looked for the implementation in the [source code](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes), but I am unable to find it.

I wrote a simple application and ran it in the iPhone Simulator, but no value is shown. The application was created by running `rhogen app phone_id`. I then added the following line to the `app/application.rb` file just before the call to `super`:

```
@phoneId = System.get_property('phone_id')
```

Then I added this line to `app/index.erb`:

```
<p>Phone id = <span><%= @phoneId %></span></p>
```

I know that the simulator will return a unique identifier because I wrote an actual iOS application that merely writes the unique identifier to a label with the following bit of code:

```
[idLabel setText:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];
```

Since I don't know Ruby, and I particularly don't know Rhodes, I am unsure if the Rhodes test application I wrote is working correctly. So, I don't know if the call to `System.get_property` is working as it should or if it should really be returning an identifier.

Thus my question, does `System.get_property('phone_id')` always return a value? If so, is that value guaranteed to be unique? Or are there cases where the method will return `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to messages [cb41fb9718773a21](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/msg/cb41fb9718773a21) and [0d4ff1aaaaa9e560](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/msg/0d4ff1aaaaa9e560) on the Rhomobile Google group, this method *is not* guaranteed to return any value other than `nil`. Thus you cannot rely on `System.get_property('phone_id')` to return a unique identifier for your application.